# How to create a media item in sitecore 6.5 using item web api

Tags: c#, sitecore, asp.net-web-api, sitecore6

We are using Sitecore 6.5 in the project.

In one of the sites of the project the user has to be able to upload pdf / doc files to the server. When he  uploads this is getting added to the web db so we have to transfer it to the master db.

I'm trying to accomplish this by using the item web api of Sitecore.

I have looked at [this post](http://www.sitecoreinsight.com/how-create-media-items-using-sitecore-item-web-api/) on how to do it. But I can't get it working.

Whenever I execute my request, I get an internal server error telling me that the layout for the requested document was not found.

The generated url I have is this:

```
{host}/-/item/v1/?name=45c87793-4b37-40c8-acbc-a3b8f2b0c275&sc_itemid=653a9a07-6ea0-4e9a-8214-6bf3447096ed&sc_database=master&payload=min
```

As far as I know, I think the url is built up correct.

Executing a get request does work by using below url:

```
{host}/-/item/v1/?sc_itemid=653a9a07-6ea0-4e9a-8214-6bf3447096ed
```

Any ideas on what I'm missing?

Edit:

Here's the code on how I call the media poster.

```
var mediaPoster = new MediaPoster("http://{host}/", @"sitecore\admin", "b");

if (pdfStream != null)
     mediaPoster.PostMedia(item.Name, new Guid("{653A9A07-6EA0-4E9A-8214-6BF3447096ED}"), "master", new MemoryStream(pdfStream.ToArray()), ".pdf");
```

Comment: Hi, can you add the code where you call mp.PostMedia? What is the extension of this file. I see you used a guid as the file name, is that what you intend?

Comment: Hi Roberto, I've added the code where I call the PostMedia function. The extension as you can see in the code sample is a pdf. And it is my intent to use a guid as file name.

Answer (score 0):

also verify your configuration is correct. To upload files you need to set security.

```
  <site name="website">
    <patch:attribute name="itemwebapi.mode">StandardSecurity</patch:attribute>
    <patch:attribute name="itemwebapi.access">ReadWrite</patch:attribute>
    <patch:attribute name="itemwebapi.allowanonymousaccess">false</patch:attribute>
  </site>
```

I just ran a test with that configuration in place and it worked.

You can create a console application and with the PostMedia class use this code:

```
string HOST = @"http://HOST/";
string ParentID = "{3D6658D8-A0BF-4E75-B3E2-D050FABCF4E1}";         //Must be media library folder/item. this is the root
string mediaFileExt = ".pdf";                                       //you need to specify the extension. You can get that by the content-type returned or the way you find better.

HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("http://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sdn5/modules/sitecore%20item%20web%20api/sitecore_item_web_api_developer_guide_sc65-66-usletter.pdf");
HttpWebResponse httpWebReponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
Stream mediaStream = httpWebReponse.GetResponseStream();


//create a instance and inform the credentials as well the host
MediaPost mp = new MediaPost(HOST, @"sitecore\admin", "b");

//post the media!
//Important: It needs a Valid Item Name,
//                    a Valid Parent ID under Media Library,
//                    the database, the stream and the extension
mp.PostMedia("DocumentName", new Guid(ParentID), "master", mediaStream, mediaFileExt);
```

It should work, let know if you still getting that error...

**UPDATE**:

Do you know the showconfig.aspx in Sitecore? You can use it to see how your configuration files got parsed. 
I'd suggest to you to go there `http://HOST/sitecore/admin/showconfig.aspx`, search for `<sites>` and see how your website is set. All the patch attributes(mode, access, allowanonumousaccess) should be like in the configuration above.

As long as your user is admin it should have access to the medialibrary and all other security aspects.

Another point I just thought. Did you get the right version of the Item Web Api module for your Sitecore version.

1.0

> The Sitecore Item Web API module v1.0.0 rev.120828 is released.
>   The Sitecore Item Web API module has been tested with Sitecore CMS 6.5.0
>   rev.120706 (Update-5) and CMS 6.6.0 rev.120918  (Initial release).

1.2

> The Sitecore Item Web API 1.2.0 rev. 140128 is released.
>   The Sitecore Item Web API module has been tested with Sitecore CMS 6.6.0 rev.
>   131211 (6.6.0 Update-7) and 7.1 rev. 140130 (7.1 Update-1).

Comment: Hi Roberto. I forgot to install the package Sitecore.ItemWebApi... (Dumb.. I know.. But I thought it wasn't necessary as retrieving items worked.) 
I've installed it now and getting a different error after I've set the configuration options you provided me. So I think I'll be able to continue from here on.
Thanks for your answer!

Comment: I've continued trying around and I still get an error. More specifically, the error occurs in the following class: Sitecore.ItemWebApi.Pipelines.HttpRequest.CheckMode. Apparently the mode is set to OFF. While in my .config file I'm 100% sure it's set to StandardSecurity. I.e. The options you gave me above.

Comment: I've managed to fix the above issue. But now I get an OK status, but by using postman I can see that the response that is actually given is the following: "Access to site is not granted." Which is strange because I'm using the admin user.. I've tried on the media library itself and on a folder within the library.

Comment: Hi.. I updated the answer to make it easier to read.. take a look there. Cheers

Comment: Hi. Yes I know about the showconfig. I used it to check the sites settings, but we are using MultiSiteManager instead of sites.config. So I had to modify everything in there. That is all working now. My site has those settings, I've checked it while debugging. And I took version 1.0 of the sitecore Web API module as we have Sitecore.NET 6.5.0 (rev. 121009). So I think all those settings are correct.